# Is there an equivalent to the Background section to run steps after scenarios?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

When writing cucumber tests in gherkin one can define a series of steps, that will be executed before each scenario

I could not find any equivalent to that for running a series of steps *after each* scenario.

My use case would be:

```
Background:
  - login
  - go to products page
  - select product

Scenario Outline:
  - Configure product in different ways

  Examples:
    | options |
    | values  |

After Each:
  - go to checkout
  - fill in personal data
  - fill in payment data
  - submit
```

Is there such an equivalent option that I missed in the docs?

Comment: You could use an after hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an after equivalent by design. The point of each scenario in Cucumber is to drive the development of a particular bit of behaviour specified by the `When`. Because new behaviour mostly builds on existing behaviour its expected that a number of scenarios will have a common background. For example if you are writing scenarios about signing into a website (good sign in, bad password, forgotten password ...), your users will have to be registered.

The `Then` in a scenario is to assert that the `When` has worked. Anything after that should be in a different scenario.

So your examples could be

```
Given a product is configured with ...
When I buy the product
Then ...
```

All the after stuff gets moved into the before stuff, and possibly the When.